# Connect Unix and Windows using shell script

Tags: shell-script, windows, sftp

```
SRCDIR="source/directory"
TMPDIR="temp/directory"
[ ! -d "$TMPDIR" ] && mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"
for file in `find "$SRCDIR" -ctime -1 -type f -name "abc*pdf*"`; do
    cp $file $TMPDIR
done
cd $TMPDIR
ext=`echo $file1|awk -F. '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'`
if [ $ext == "Z" ]; then
uncompress $file1
fi
done
```

I want to transfer file from Unix to Windows which are in `$TMPDIR`. But I don't know how to connect Unix to Windows in the script.

I am using `psftp` to transfer files from Unix to Windows manually. I want to automate this process using script.Can I use `psftp` in script or can it be done using `batch` script? Could someone help me how can I connect Unix to Windows.

Comment: Why don't you make a share on Windows, mount it then copy the files to it? Alternatively you could use **smbclient**.

Comment: You can use cygwin64 and password-less ssh as well.

Comment: You can have a batch script which runs something like: psftp someLoginName@someIP -pw somePassword -b "get /some/place/on/the/unix/box"

Comment: Do you want to run that transfer script on the Windows machine or on the Unix machine? How is the script that you show related to the file transfer script that you want to write?

Comment: @ Gilles The script I want to written in Unix, but i do not know how to connect unix and windows.